# Using Chinese 3018 CNC mill with KiCAD and FlatCAM for PCBs - "tool change"

Tags: pcb, kicad, cnc

OK here's the deal, KiCAD of course does a wonderful job with schematics, footprints, Gerber files, they even provide a pretty decent autorouter. Then you take the Gerbers and Excellons over into FlatCAM and they use those to make geometries and "job files" (G-code).

And so far I just have a minimal 3018 machine (probably a RATTM controller, I'm not sure) running GRBL 1.1h and I talk to it with LaserGRBL (even though I have no laser). Well I though I was on top of the world until I tried actually executing the G-code corresponding to the Excellons (drills), which of course were at several different diameters, so when I generated those files I clicked on "tool change", but when I tried to run the resulting file into the machine it choked on the "M6" (tool change) code generated.

Well at THIS price I obviously realized I wasn't getting any AUTOMATED tool change, but I DID expect the machine to stop and notify me SOMEHOW that it was time to go to the next tool (drill). Well then I unchecked "tool change" and went through the same procedure, and I looked at the G-code and saw to my horror that it had generated code to drill ALL the holes with the initial drill diameter in the machine!

Well I don't know what command exists in G-code to "halt for intervention", and if there were one I wouldn't want to manually edit it into ALL these job files, and I suppose "worst case" I MIGHT have to break all these job files into a SEPARATE file for each diameter, what a PITA!

So what I want to know is what are my alternatives for an even SLIGHTLY "enlightened" code stack? Is there a credible "alternative" for either GRBL or FlatCAM so I don't have to completely "invent a new workflow" JUST to accommodate the "revelation" that - wait for it - holes in PCBs occasionally actually have MORE THAN ONE diameter?

Has anyone else found a simple way to circumvent this? (I mean what a letdown after SO MANY other problems in this flow have finally been resolved!) Thank you in advance for your time and insight!

Comment: (1) ***HuaZhong 850  CNC***: 
https://www.hcnc-group.com/cnc-machine/machining-center/cnc-machining-center.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwiuuRBhBvEiwAFXKaNOMYloMa54zzDPz6MfWyMqHIv1u-c453IiKMi_uRLTDdzxNcE5pfdhoC5BMQAvD_BwE

(2) ***3018 CNC*** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFkz4IztVsU

Answer (score 1):

Use the Excellon preprocessor in Flatcam that excludes the M6 code, which should be GRBL_11_no_M6 or something similar.

Set up your desired tool change position too, obviously.

Comment: OK a preprocessor...who knew...